# WPF get Content of a treeviewitem

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I need to check what `treeviewitem` the user selected everytime it changes. I used the `SelectedItemChanged`method or whatever this is called. It works fine but now I need to do a `switch case` for every possible `treeviewitem`. But I can't do that since I have no idea how to get the name of it. I checked on internet but some people said to use `treeview.SelectedItem` but it returns `System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem Header: Items.Count:0`. I was wondering if I could do that entirely in the .cs code file or if I had to use data binding and such.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

Here is how i setup the treeview and the treeviewitems. They are all like the second example.

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeview" Margin="10,10,0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="192" Background="#FFA45353" SelectedItemChanged="treeview_SelectedItemChanged"">
        <TreeViewItem IsExpanded="False">
            <TreeViewItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="./Resources/smallicons/icon.jpg"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" Main" FontSize="14"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </TreeViewItem.Header>
            <!--==============================================================================================-->
            <TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="First" Foreground="Black" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </TreeViewItem.Header>
            </TreeViewItem>
            <!--==============================================================================================-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
TreeViewItem selectedNode = (TreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem;
string strSelectedNode = selectedNode.Header.ToString();
```

The above snippet assumes a **few things** though.

By the way, this code is part of

```
private void TreeViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem selectedNode = (TreeViewItem)treeView.SelectedItem;
    MessageBox.Show(selectedNode.Header.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok...As per your treeview and treeview Item setup, you have to code something like this..

```
private void treeview_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {    
            TreeViewItem selectedNode = (TreeViewItem)treeview.SelectedItem;
            var sp = selectedNode.Header as StackPanel;
            var tb = sp.Children[0] as TextBlock;
            var selecteditem = tb.Text;
            //MessageBox.Show(selecteditem);
            switch (selecteditem)
            {
                case "Main":
                    MessageBox.Show(selecteditem);
                    break;
                case "First":
                    MessageBox.Show(selecteditem);
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("no matching item found");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Here, I am digging in the selected tree view item to get the Text of selected tree view item. You may have to tweak the code a bit to get it fully operational. Let me know if you need any help with it.

Comment: I am not having my laptop as of now so can't code it but here, you have to get stackpanel child of type text block and it will did the trick for you. As of now, children [0] is returning image and hence it's failing.